# Passing variable to directive's attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In AngularJS, how can I use a variable within an attribute of a directive?

Without any directives, this work fine:

```
<a 
    href="#/fruits/{{ fruit.short }}/details" 
    title="Back to Fruit details">
    Back
</a>
```

Now with directive, this does not work:

```
<backButton 
    href="#/fruits/{{ fruit.short }}/details" 
    title="Fruit details">
</backButton>


MyApp.directive( 'backbutton', function() 
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) 
        {
            var href    = attrs.href;
            var title   = attrs.title;

            console.log( "href = " + href );    // undefined
            console.log( "title = " + title );  // Fruit details

            element.html('<a href="' + href + '" title="Back to ' + title + '">Back</a>');
        }
    };
});
```

The directive itself works fine for e.g. `href="#/fruits/novariableused"`. But as soon as I use a variable in the `href` attribute, its value becomes `undefined`.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular will interpolate your href attribute after the linking process, however you can observe the attrs. It's in the docs: [Directive Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Attributes)

```js
attrs.$observe('href', function ( value ) {
    // here you have the href
});
```

See it in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/BB9TW/)

Comment: I was looking for the same. This saved a lot of my time.

Comment: This helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

var myButtonFn = function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {href: "="},
    template: "<a ng-href='{{href}}' ng-transclude></a>"
  };
};

app.directive("myButton", myButtonFn);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">

  <my-button href="'http://www.google.com/'">Button</my-button>

</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/iwucaw/1/edit

Comment: While I assume that this works in principle, it doesn't explain how to make it work with `link: function` (like in my example) rather than with `template:`. Oliver's answer does explain this, so I will choose his answer as the correct one.